# Keep lock for multiple updates to a single row in SQL

Tags: sql, mariadb

I want to lock a certain single row in a MariaDb table for multiple updates, and would like to release the lock when I'm finished updating it. The scenarios is multiple machines could be requesting the lock. When one machine gets the lock, it has a batch of work that needs to update the row data multiple times. The other machine may not get a chance at the lock while the first machine is still busy with it's batch of work. So if the first machine does two updates, the other machine may not get the lock between the two updates.

I've looked at transactions, but they do a rollback if my application crashes, whereas I want the updates to remain.

Does anyone have an idea on how to solve this kind of issue? Googling it does not produce any good hits, or my search terms might be wrong.

**Edit:

Trying to clarify the use case a bit more:**
This functionality is for event processing in a distributed system, where there are multiple concurrent consumers.
The events are parts of streams, and the events within a stream must be processed in the correct order, otherwise the system gets corrupted.
For all kinds of reasons the events of a single stream can end up on different consumers, in the wrong orders, with a large delay, etcetera, these are exceptional cases, not normal operation conditions.

The locking of rows helps making sure that different consumers are not working on the same event stream concurrently

```
BEGIN;
SELECT counter, someAdditionalFields FROM streamCounters WHERE streamId=x FOR UPDATE; 
# this locks the stream to this consumer
# This thread is processing event with eventId counter+1, this can be in the range of 0ms to a few seconds, certainly not minutes. 
# The result of this work ends up in another table
UPDATE streamCounters SET counter=(counter+1) WHERE streamId=x; 
# signifies that event was processed, the stream advances by 1
# This thread is processing event with eventId counter+2
UPDATE streamCounters SET counter=(counter+2) WHERE streamId=x;
# signifies that event was processed, the stream advances by 1
# ... until no more ready events available in stream
COMMIT; # release the lock on this stream
```

The reason I don't want this transaction to roll back in case of a crash, is because the processing of the events means significant change in other tables.
The changes in the other tables are done by a different part of the application, they provide me a function that I call, what they do is not really under my control.

Lets say I want to process event 1 in a stream, I lock the stream.
I call provided function that processes event 1.
When it returns with success, i update the streamcounter from 0 to 1
Now I want to process event 2, but I crash.
Now this transaction gets rolled back, streamcounter goes back to 0, but event was processed. 
My streamcounter does now not represent how much work was done!

Comment: Search for nowait, nolock commands

Comment: It sounds like you have a queue within a queue -- There are a queue of "streams".  Within a stream, there is a queue of "events".  You mention "consumers" of events, but it seems like you need some mechanism for dispatching a stream's events to consumers.  And for making sure they are done in order.  Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, you could say that, a stream is a virtual queue of events belonging to one entity. However due to the distributed nature of the system and error handling, events within a stream could arrive like so: 1,3,4,5,2. Note that these events could also interleave with other stream's events. It must be handled like 1,2,3,4,5 of course.

Comment: > You mention "consumers" of events, but it seems like you need some mechanism for dispatching a stream's events to consumers. And for making sure they are done in order. Am I correct?
Almost always the events already arrive in the correct order. In this particular situation events arrived in the wrong order, like 1,3,4, 2. The system already processed event 1, tries to process 3, sees that there is a gap and stores events 3 and 4 for later processing. When event 2 arrives on the queue, it is handled. Now it has to retrieve the temporary stored 3 and 4 and process them.